# Angular-js ng-hide and very large images

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) for `ng-hide` says that it just adds a CSS directive:

```
<!-- when $scope.myValue is truthy (element is hidden) -->
<div ng-hide="myValue" class="ng-hide"></div>

<!-- when $scope.myValue is falsy (element is visible) -->
<div ng-hide="myValue"></div>
```

which it defines as :

```
.ng-hide {
  /* this is just another form of hiding an element */
  display: block!important;
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

If I have a very large image, more than 9999 pixels in any dimension, won't it then intrude into the viewport?

And are there any security implications? Since the hidden element is still in the DOM, anyone can see it. Does this mean that I ought to use `ng-if` for sensitive data?

```
<div ng-if="userType == admin">
   < list of user names and passwords>
```

Comment: ngIf seems more reasonable in your case with sensitive data

Answer (score 3):

For sensitive data you should make sure that it doesn't even get in the app if the user isn't authorized to see it. But `ng-hide` just indeed hides the content, while `ng-if` only renders the content when the conditions are met.

Talking about a very large image, you'll also always want to use `ng-if`. Drawing large images has a huge performance hit on your app, using `ng-hide` also slows down your app in that case.

Comment: not "only renders" but puts or removes a block in the DOM as ts wrote

Comment: I agree on the sensitive data, what do you think of a very large image? Will it leak into the viewport?

Comment: Added that part to the answer

Comment: Is part of the image visible, if you make it larger than 9999 pixels in either dimension and `ng-hide` it?

Comment: I guess it would, as it just simple css. But you will never want to use such a big image in your app, as it would cause huge loading times.